# What is the purpose of the macro : GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am trying to port an OpenGL application from Mac to iOS. The code is like this

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH,  4*COMPASS_SIZE);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS,   row*COMPASS_SIZE);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, col*COMPASS_SIZE);
glDrawPixels(COMPASS_SIZE, COMPASS_SIZE, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, compassBits);
```

Here the texture is read from a image file which contains many compass
Here COMPASS_SIZE is exactly equal to the dimension of each compass in the image.
What I dont understand is what is the purpose of the first line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sets number of pixels in a row, so that skipping rows would know how to advance pointer to obtain the next compass line address.

Judging from this line you have four compasses in a row.

Comment: Ok..I got it. Thanks..But I have one question. How do we implement this functionality since the macro GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH is not available for OpenGL ES

Comment: @Anupam you would have to read it line-by-line in the loop to another texture and then draw it.